# How to run an animation after segue immediately without any delay?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewanimation

I am running a slidein animation on an inner view of a new `UIViewController` which has been load. The problem is, because the animation can only be excecuted in `ViewDidAppear()`, that there is a delay between when the `ViewController` did load and when the animation starts. Because of this delay, it seems that the app has performance issues.

How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `viewWillAppear` should solve your problem.

The animation code should be asynchronously because inside of `viewWillAppear` the view hasn't appeared yet

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.appearanceAnimation()
    }
}

func appearanceAnimation() {
    //Add animaton here
}
```